# Stop people from accessing HTML form externally

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have JQuery currently doing the validation on my website, however if another person submits a form with the same data to my page they can get past the validation that my JQuery does, so my question is this:  How do I stop people from externally submitting forms to my website?

If there is a solution with PHP that would be preferred.

Comment: **always** validate server-side, even if you want to validate client side as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is very simple

**Never ever trust the client side validation** - Any validation done in the client side has to be replicated in the server side also

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend doing server side validation as well. If a user comes to your site with javascript disabled in the browser then your JQuery validation also becomes null and void.

Answer (score 1):

Use client side as well as server side validation.

Client side validation will not work it user "Disable Javascript" from client.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery form validation is great but it can easily be bypassed if someone disables Javascript in their browser.

Your best bet is to validate the user data on the server side using PHP. You can do this by checking the POST variable which stores all the user data submitted through your form then write validation tests to check the data.

And as the other posters have said, **don't ever trust client side validation**